# LibreOffice 5 command line convert to PDF producing error

Tags: windows, pdf, command-line, libreoffice

I am trying to convert a Word Doc to PDF using LibreOffice 5 on a Windows Web Server. Whenever I run the script I get the following error:

> soffice - Fatal Error: The program cannot be started. A general error
>   occurred while accessing your central configuration. SafeMode is
>   initiated. ("component context fails to supply service
>   com.sun.star.configuration.ReadWriteAccess of type
>   com.sun.star.configuration.ReadWriteAccess")

This is the command I am using

> "C:\Program Files (x86)\LibreOffice 5\program\soffice.exe" -headless
>   -convert-to pdf:writer_pdf_Export -outdir C:\ C:\QuoteLetter.doc

It keeps putting a safemode file in the LibreOffice program folder. Any ideas on how I can stop it from going into SafeMode or what is causing it to?

Comment: `libreoffice --convert-to pdf "/home/rolf/Documents/Untitled 1.docx"` works fine using LO 5.4.0.3 (Linux) - (make sure that neither LO nor quickstarter is running at the time)

Comment: Check to see if the source file (Untitled 1.docx) is already open in an editor (like Word).   This seems to trigger this error with recent versions of Libre Office but why I can't say currently.

Comment: Perhaps check your path to soffice.  I just noticed that this fails with the same error: "c:\Program Files (x86)\...."\soffice.exe but "c:\Program Files (x86)\....\soffice.exe" works.  So if your path has the quotes in the wrong place this error also occurs.